# Use Clang to emit LLVM IR with array info

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

I am currently using Clang as my C front end to emit LLVM IR. I try to compile a function named `foo`:

```
void foo(float A[256]) {...}
```

The command I used was:

```
clang -Xclang -emit-llvm -S -c foo.cpp -o foo.ll
```

In my `foo.ll` I have:

```
define void @foo(float* %A) ...
```

As you can see, `A` is now a pointer instead of an array. What should I do to generate something like the following:

```
define void @foo(float* [256 x f32] %A) ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: `void foo(float (&A)[256]) {...}` to pass an array by reference.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers automatically in most cases (passing as arguments, applying the index or dereferencing operator, ...). For function parameters sizes of arrays are simply ignored, `float a[256]` is equivalent to `float a[]` and to `float*`. The only thing a concrete size can serve for is documenting to the user what actually is expected (at least, array might be longer). You could enforce *exact* array length (but no minimum) with `float (*a)[256]`, no you have a pointer to array of fix size. Note that you now need to call like this: `float a[256]; foo(&a)`.

Comment: Using a VLA you can extend this to `void foo(size_t size, float(*a)[size]);` – note, though, that this is *not* valid C++, so you need to restrain from if you want to be compatible to both C and C++ (as you added both language flags; if you are only interested in C please remove the C++ tag, otherwise please add a corresponding line to question to justify both tags).

Comment: *'C front end'* vs. `foo.cpp` – which one now? C or C++?

Comment: Thanks, both! @Eljay's answer allows me to get what I want in LLVM IR. I am building an llvm pass that requires this array information, so I was expecting that there may be an existing option in Clang/LLVM that I can use to get something like this for any program... I am surprised that there isn't! The C/C++ tag meant my input to be parsed.

Comment: Note that there is no C/C++ tag – there is no language like C/C++, C and C++ are different languages. C is compatible to C++ on a pretty wide range, but there are quite a number of issues in which they differ:

Comment: Character literals like `'s'` have type `int` in C, but `char` in C++ (so `sizeof('s')` usually gives different results), string literals are `char*` in C and `char const*` in C++, `void*` pointers cast implicitly in C but not in C++ (`int* a = malloc(7);` is valid in C but not in C++), type punning via unions is legal in C but UB in C++, `main` can be called from other locations in C but not in C++, not returning a value from a function with non-void return type is always UB in C++ (apart from `main`), in C only if the return value is actually used, ...

Comment: So while most C-code can be compiled as C++ as well, it is easily possible to produce invalid C++ code with totally valid C.